# How to focus on a window, in windows using ruby

Tags: ruby

How do i focus on a window in ruby? This is my code:

```
require 'win32ole'

win = WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell")
win.run("notepad.exe")
win.SendKeys("This is automatic")
```

I want to focus on the "notepad.exe" window

Comment: Try win.AppActivate("Notepad") before sendkeys

Comment: I found out that the code you was right, but you need to put it in this path: AppActivate("#{win}")